# ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity i9.NgxFileDropModule to symbol

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have migrated angular 8 to version 10. Application is using custom angular library which is also being migrated from version 7 to 10.
this library has NgxFileDropModule which is imported as

```
(import { NgxFileDropModule } from 'ngx-file-drop';)
```

but the error is thrown in main application **ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity i9.NgxFileDropModule to symbol**
How do I get rid of this issue
P.s. library is compiled and built well but main application throws error which has dependency on library

Comment: Experiencing the same trouble. Have you found a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Parul have you figured out yet? I am facing similar issue, have update V11- V12

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem while having the library locally sourced using `file:` package target.
My solution was to set `projects.PROJECTNAME.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks` to `true`.

e.g.

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "PROJECTNAME": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        // ...
      },
      // ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            // ...
            "scripts": [],
            "preserveSymlinks": true // <-- This line here
          }
          // Remaining configuration...
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the issue when I run `nx serve` (I'm on an NX workspace), but when I try to add `preserveSymlinks` property to `targets.serve.options` in `project.json` file it throws the following error: **'preserveSymlinks' is not found in schema**. Any idea?